# How to create a global array in robot framework? is there any keyword for that?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

As per Bryan's input, i have used  "Set Global Variable" keyword

```
Function_one
    @{List}    Create List
    :FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    0    3
    \    ${COUNT}=    Read Cell Data By Coordinates    ${xl_shtname}    ${INDEX}    {XL_Rwnum}
    \    Insert Into List    ${List}    ${INDEX}    ${count}
    \    Set Global Variable     ${List}
    \    Assign List values    ${List}
    \    Run Keyword If    '${Empl_ID}'=='A1000'    Function_Two


Assign List values
    [Arguments]    ${List_Data}

    Set Global Variable    ${FirstName}    ${List[0]}
    Set Global Variable    ${LastName}    ${List[1]}
    Set Global Variable    ${Empl_ID}    ${List[2]}
    Set Global Variable    ${Mobile}    ${List[3]}



Function_Two

    @{Emp_Name_ID}    Create List    ${FirstName}   ${Empl_ID}
    Log List    ${Emp_Name_ID}
```

Emp_Name_ID values are printed  correctly for first iteration. But , it prints the same value for second iteration also which is incorrect. Looks like global variable ${List} is not updated during second iteration.

Kindly suggest your inputs

Comment: Please don't completely rewrite your question to ask something different than the original. It invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Do not use the statement "Set Global Variable     ${List}" withing the for loop. Use it outside the loop.